# Prewhitening time series: ARIMA-modelling versus polynomial trendelimination

Tags: time-series, arima, trend, arma, cross-correlation

I'm concerned with Box-Jenkins-models and especially the first step, the prewhitening to obtain meaningful crosscorrelations for identifying transfer functions and building regression models.

I'm working with SAS and here one has to identify a suitable ARIMA-model for the input series to achive white noise and afterwards the response series is automatically filtered by the same model.

Now I'm wondering about two things:

1. If I have two series A and B and I do not know which one is the input and which one the response series (and there can be feeback maybe), do I have to set at first series A as input and filter it with a suitable ARIMA-model (and the series B is filtered like that) and I can only have a look at positive lags (and lag 0) of the crosscorrelation function (CCF) that will show how series A affects B. And as a second step do I have to choose series B as input and do the same (set a suitable ARIMA-model for B, A is filtered with the same parameters, look at the positive lags (and lag 0) of the CCF to see how B affects A) ? It seems a little bit weird to me, but it seems to be right in a logical way. But then I ask myself what to do with two different lag 0 values for example? (In some cases I got significant results in one case and when I changed input and response like described it wasn't significant)
2. What if I decided that there is a deterministic trend in one of the series (let's say series A) and I have to detrend by polynomial subtraction? In this case in SAS the response series (let's say series B) isn't filtered in the same way. Is it right to take the detrended series from A and the original series B for computing the CCF?

I would be very glad if someone can help me.

Greetings,
Daniela